# jQuery val() for array of strings

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm very new to jQuery and its uses, but I'm trying to do something simple...I have a hidden input that contains a list of strings and I'm trying to put it into an AngularJS controller.

here's my input

```
<input type="hidden" id="states" value="{!states}" />
```

and code from my controller

```
$scope.states = jQuery('#states').val();
```

yet when I try something like `alert($scope.states[0])` the alert box only contains "[", as if the first element in the states array is [, second element is A, third element is L, etc.

am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why do you need a hidden input in the first place when working with angular?

Comment: @charlietfl I'm trying to grab the value from the server. Not really sure how to do it otherwise.

Comment: would normally make a `$http` request and pass response to controller

Comment: @EmbattledSwag, usually, if you use jquery inside angular controlller - you do something wrong :-) try see this post [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: sidenote: attribute value always is string. so for getting js object, you need parse this string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transform the value from a string into an array. Try with [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/parse):

```
$scope.states = JSON.parse(jQuery('#states').val());
```

Comment: this helped, but I also had to serialize the object on the server side too. Thanks!